# What (more elegant) methods exist to parse discrete chunks of data as if they were one?

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I have a problem:  I will be getting data from an external source.  I will be getting this data in chunks, unfortunately.

The function, in psuedocode, looks like this:

```
stringy chunk;

recievedata(stringy incomingdata,number size_of_incoming_data){

chunk=malloc(size_of_incoming_data)
chunk=incomingdata
}
```

However, the incoming data is a string an *must be parsed thoroughly*, and there **is a significant chance that target words of the data will be split across chunks in a non-predictable fashion**.  This function is called by the curl library of OpenSSL, for the record, several times to pass data that is being received.

As it stands in pusedocode above, this will just keep overriding the old data.  I could fix this using a buffer, such as:

```
    stringy chunk;
    stringy buffer;

    recievedata(stringy incomingdata,number size_of_incoming_data){

    if (chunk is assigned) {
      buffer = chunk;
      chunk=malloc(size_of_incoming_data+size_of_old_data)
      chunk = buffer + incomingdata
      free (buffer)
    }    
    }
```

Alas, this seems kind of horrible. I find it extremely ugly that I have two have two copies of the same data for no functional reason.  Because this is something of a deamon running a machine that has other things to do, I need to be as conservative as possible with resources such as memory.

Would anyone be so kind as to enlighten me as to the most efficient methods that are available for handling data in this manner?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to implement stream parsing logic. On every `recievedata` call you should add new data to some buffer, and analyze this buffer. If buffer contains the full message, handle this message and clean the buffer. If message is not full, leave it as is waiting for completion. You can also implement some timeout handling logic, to clean the buffer with incomplete data, if new data was not received during some time interval.

Comment: OT: It's `receive` not `recieve`.

Comment: @AlexFarber has good advice. You should probably recognise this is exactly the problem pretty much any IO has - for instance, reading from a disk comes in blocks. You need a solution along the lines of what 'stdio` does for "normal" input.

Answer (score 0):

The customary way to work with data chunks is to build a higher level interface that treats them as a stream. For example, you might have

```
     char nextByteInStream () ;
```

to get a single byte (omitting error handling parameters). Or

```
     void nextBytes (char *, int count) ;
```

to return a a number of bytes.

In compression, it is common to have something like:

```
    unsigned int nextBits (int count) ;
```

returning one or more bits in a stream.

Use such an interface to isolate the inherent messiness of chunk data.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the following assumes no 0x00 bytes in data
// if there are 0x00 bytes, then track current size of used memory
// and use memcpy() to put incoming data into data at next available byte
// (remembering to update the index to the next available byte in the
// allocated memory


char *data = malloc(1);
*data = '\0';
char *temp = NULL;

recievedata(stringy incomingdata,number size_of_incoming_data)
{
    temp = realloc( data, strlen(data)+size_of_incoming_data  );
    if( NULL != temp )
    { // then successful realloc
         data = temp;
         strncat( data, incomingdata, size_of_incoming_data );
    }
    else
    { // handle realloc error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul says in the comments, this is very common producer-consumer buffering problem.  The `receivedata` callback is the producer.  The parser is the consumer.  The buffer is the communication channel between them.  It has a fill pointer to show end of current data.

Each time `receivedata` runs,

- Concatenate the new data to what's already there (by copying to the fill pointer location) and advance the fill pointer.
- Run the parser to consume as many complete words (your term) as possible.  Parsing of the last word may fail because it's not complete.
- Copy any the incomplete word to the start of the buffer. And set the fill pointer adjusted to its end.

In C:

```
char *buf = NULL;
size_t fill_ptr = 0, buf_size = 0;

static void expand_buffer_to(size_t size) {
  if (size < buf_size) {
    buf = realloc(buf, size);
    if (buf == NULL) handle_realloc_fail();
    buf_size = size;
  }
}

void receivedata(char *incoming_data, size_t size_of_incoming_data) {

  // Make sure the buffer is big enough to accept new data.
  expand_buffer_to(fill_ptr + size_of_incoming_data);

  // Concatenate to end of buffer.
  memcpy(buf + fill_ptr, incoming_data, size_of_incoming_data);

  // Adjust fill pointer to include new data.
  fill_ptr += size_of_incoming_data;

  // Run the parser. fill_ptr is input size.  
  // Return number of characters parsed successfully.
  size_t n_chars_parsed = parse_words(buf, fill_ptr);

  // Move any incomplete word chars (maybe 0) to the start of the buffer.
  memmove(buf, buf + n_chars_parsed, fill_ptr - n_chars_parsed);

  // Move fill pointer to end of incomplete word.
  fill_ptr -= n_chars_parsed;
}
```

This is more-or-less how all I/O of variable length records works.  NB some have talked about the stream abstraction, and this is a nice way to go if character-by-character handling is desired.  However IME introducing a character stream abstraction tends toward code with more layers of copying and buffering than is really needed.  By passing the parser a buffer load of data at a time as above, it's easier to avoid that.  Of course if your application is not performance critical, it won't make any difference.